# Buffering using a field in ArcPy - syntax issue?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, buffer

I am planning to add a line into my python script to buffer a feature by a field I have calculated

Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (_01_FULLSCRIPT_ANGLETEST.py, line 320)
Failed to execute (ExtractJunctionsforSCRIMSitecategories).
```

Line 320:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(ExpNod + "/FILE2BUFFER.shp",ExpNod + "/BUFFER1.shp","DISTSTRING","FULL","ROUND","NONE","#")
```

ExpNod is a defined folder, this works fine in every other line
FILE2BUFFER.shp is my input, BUFFER1.shp is my output and the name of the field containing the value to buffer (in this instance it's -4 Meters, but it variable due to an input made by the user at the start of the script).

Comment: You'll need to try to isolate the part of your code that's causing this and create an example that is reproducible. As-is, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with this, since we don't know how you actually defined those variables.

Comment: Try displaying those variables with something like arcpy.AddMessage("my message") so we know what's being done by arcgis.

Comment: Two options - convert the buffer distance field to float or integer OR add the units to the buffer distance ('-4 Meters' instead of '-4').  Your code is failing because it either needs a number or needs the units in the string.

Comment: You need to update your questions with solutions you find.  Don't put them in the comments where they get lost.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer distance might be a string (the name and quotes suggest this) but should be a number or a named linear unit like "100 Meters".

If the variable is actually carrying a number you should not use the quotes there as it will pass a string without the needed linear unit. When you pass a number it will use the default unit of your CRS.

If the variable is truly a string cast the value to number first or concatenate with the needed linear unit.

Comment: The field name needs to be within quotes.  Your answer works otherwise, so please remove that part and I'll remove my downvote.  The attributes within that field need to be either an integer or string with units defined, as you said.  What you said about the quotes is incorrect.  If you remove the quotes, you're calling a variable.

Comment: He wrote it is a variable that is put in by the user at the start. That means its not a field and therefore no parentheses. In its comment he wrote what worked for him, which are triple parentheses. Thats not a very clear and readable way but leads to coercing a variable into text that is then correctly put into parentheses again that the tool understands it. But a normal variable like puffer = 1000 can be put into the tool as just plain puffer without the " .

Comment: your correct, but he specified that he was adding a field as buffer distance.  FYI these are parentheses - () and these are quotes - "".  Can you please clarify your answer.  You need to specify clearly that IF you're using a variable you don't need quotes - even if the variable is holding a string.  If you're using a field, you need quotes unless you've already defined the field as a variable.  The problem is that Alan Carr did not update his question with the solution he found and I did not see his comment.

Comment: You have to edit your answer if you want me to remove my downvote.  I can't remove it unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Now i got you, thank you very much. Had the wrong word in mind all the time.

Comment: Thanks @Matte.  I removed by vote, but I'm still confused by your answer.  I think you should reword it to say that the attribute values themselves need or don't need quotes.  OR clarify that if you're using a variable in the buffer function, it should not have quotes.  To me, your answer reads as though you should put quotes or not around the variable depending on the type.  A variable is a variable and shouldn't have quotes around it.